# How can I increase the number of background points when running MaxEnt in R

Tags: r, modeling, maxent

I am using the DISMO R package to run MaxEnt.
I put in ngb=10000, but it seems to be ignored.

My code is:

```
meX1_2 <-maxent(
  Present_stack, 
  X1_2,
  nbg=10000, 
  factors="litology_ASC_Present",
  args=c("maximumbackground=40000", "randomtestpoints=25")
)
```

The output still says:
225 presence records used for training.
4465 points used to determine the Maxent distribution (background points and presence points).

However, when I run MaxEnt using the "normal" user interface, I do get +10000 points used to determine the distribution, using exactly the same predictors and presences.

Any idea of why this may be and how to increase the number of background points in R?

Many thanks.